# Jekyll blog highligth code produce invalid html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, pygments, kramdown

Using Jekyll, I have this file:

```
#_posts/2015-06-20-post.textile
blablabla:

{% highlight bash  %}
$ ruby example_blocks_1.rb
[0, 2, 4, 6]
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
{% endhighlight  %} 

bla bla bla
```

this is the html produced:

```
<p>blablabla:</p>
<p><div class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-bash" data-lang="bash"><span class="gp">$ </span>ruby example_blocks_1.rb
<span class="o">[</span>0, 2, 4, 6]
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world</code></pre></div></p>
<p>blablabla</p>
```

If you put the html in a validator like this: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ 
you can see:

```
Error: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.
```

It seems html is not correct, you can see the reference here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1
Infact p tag can't contain block-level tags

Jekyll produce html for me and I can't fix the behavior. It seems a bug.

this is my `_config.yml`

```
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Since square brackets have a special meaning in markdown, escaping it should help: `\[0, 2, 4, 6\]`.

Comment: Sorry but don't works for me

Comment: @user1066183 I believe you can get rid of this issue by adding a tab or 4 spaces for everything between [0,2,4,6] and the last hello world? That tells markdown that it's a code block. Don't have jekyll on this machine so give that a go

Comment: @matrixanomaly thanks I have solved parsing all white spaces in the code. See my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.** The problem was the white space after the

> }

Example:

```
{% endhighlight  %}
```

there are 2 spaces before last % and after the last } there are others white spaces (we can't see them but they are present)